# Is it possibile Add a default function (constructor) to JS Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

This is my Code

```
var obj={a:1,b:2}
```

I don't want to change the code above (it's from somewhere else)
I am searching for a way to add a function (constructor maybe) to the object.
So users will be able to run obj()

I thought about

- obj=function () {} // It is deleting all the keys above
- obj.contructor=function () {} // Not Working

Do you have other idea?

Comment: What do you mean by *"default function (constructor)"*? Because nothing in the question or your own answer to it relates to making a default anything, and uses no constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Since functions are also objects in JavaScript, you can do this:

```js
var x = function() {
  return 0;
};
x.a = 1;
x.b = 2;

document.body.textContent = x() + ' ' + x.a + ' ' + x.b;
```

Answer (score -3):

In the middle of asking the question I found an answer:
Use the `extend` function

```
new_obj=function () {alert('the new function')}
obj=jQuery.extend(new_obj,obj)

//New I can run:

obj.a // 1
obj.b // 2
obj() // will show an alert
```

Comment: `new_obj=obj` doesn't do anything, since you're replacing it wit the function, afterwards. What you're doing here is: `var x = function(){}; x.a = 1; x.b = 2;`